# Stata twoway: How to center x-axis title with by() option

Tags: stata

When I create this twoway graph using the `by()` option, the x-axis title is not centered on the inner plot region (it is centered relative to the whole figure). This does not look good, especially with long value labels on the y-axis. Is there anyway to center the x-title properly?

```
sysuse auto, clear
twoway (scatter price weight), ylabel(, angle(horizontal)) by(foreign)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Nick, I think you meant this link: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1705680-twoway-how-to-center-x-axis-title-with-by-option

Answer (score 0):

Adding space to `xtitle` is intuitive but you may need to experiment to get the right space size. Alternatively, adding margin to the right may get it more like centered.

```
sysuse auto, clear
twoway (scatter price weight),ylabel(, angle(horizontal)) by(, plotregion(margin(1 12 1 1))) by(foreign)
```

You can change those margin values. BTW, I am using Stata 14. I think the default `xtitle` is centered on the graph but the graph may not be symmetrical.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would prefer to maximize the use of the space in the graph. Increasing the margin leaves a blank space on the right.